# Create a MegaMenu using a walker and the start_lvl function

Tags: menus, walker

I'm trying to create a normal dropdown menu and a megamenu in WP by using a custom walker.

The problem that I have is that the usual `ul` tag needs to be replaced with a `div`.

I already created the an extra checkbox to enable the megamenu by using the 
`wp_update_nav_menu_item` and `wp_setup_nav_menu_item` filters.

```
function custom_menu_fields( $menu_item ) { 
    $menu_item->is_mega_menu = get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID, '_menu_item_megamenu', true );
    return $menu_item;
}
add_filter('wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'custom_menu_fields');


function fields_update($menu_id, $menu_item_db_id, $args) {         
    if ( isset($_REQUEST['menu-item-megamenu']) && is_array($_REQUEST['menu-item-megamenu'])) {
        $custom_value = $_REQUEST['menu-item-megamenu'][$menu_item_db_id];
        update_post_meta($menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_megamenu', $custom_value);
    }   
}
add_action('wp_update_nav_menu_item', 'fields_update', 10, 3);
```

Then my walker:

```
public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {

        $indent     = str_repeat("\t", $depth);     

        if( $this->is_mega_menu && $depth == 0 ) { 
             $indent = "\t$indent";
             $output.= "$indent <div class=\"mega-menu\">\n";
        } else {
            $output.= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">\n";
        }
```

The problem is `$this->is_mega_menu`. Normally I would use `$item->is_mega_menu` or `$item->classes` but both won't work inside the `start_lvl public funtion` 
due to the `"...should be compatible with Walker::start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array)"` the moment I add `$item`.

How do I connect `$this->is_mega_menu` with the custom checkbox to enable the megamenu?
Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I used `var_dump($args)`; to see what options I have and I had to changed 
`$this->is_mega_menu` to `$args->walker->is_mega_menu`

There's still one thing left; `is_mega_menu` remains `NULL`

```
object(stdClass)#1687 (17) {    
    ....
    ["depth"]=> int(0) 

    ["walker"]=> object(Custom_Nav_Menu)#1688 (5) { 
        ["db_fields"]=> array(2) { ["parent"]=> string(16) "menu_item_parent" ["id"]=> string(5) "db_id" } 
        ["is_mega_menu"]=> NULL         
        ["has_children"]=> bool(true) 
        }   
    "theme_location"]=> string(15) "main_navigation"    
}
```